# Deploying yeoman fullstack to heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, heroku, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to deploy my Yeoman FullStack to Heroku.

I'm using the Grunt `grunt buildcontrol:heroku` to do that.

I pushed the master code to Heroku without errors

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >=0.10.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version >=0.10.0 via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.0.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.3.6
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > bson@0.2.22 install        /tmp/build_29ba4114f5a78ba9bd51197cde1a653d/node_modules/bson
remote:        > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_29ba4114f5a78ba9bd51197cde1a653d/node_modules/bson/build'
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
remote:        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_29ba4114f5a78ba9bd51197cde1a653d/node_modules/bson/build'
remote:        
remote:        > kerberos@0.0.11 install /tmp/build_29ba4114f5a78ba9bd51197cde1a653d/node_modules/kerberos
remote:        > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_29ba4114f5a78ba9bd51197cde1a653d/node_modules/kerberos/build'
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
remote:        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_29ba4114f5a78ba9bd51197cde1a653d/node_modules/kerberos/build'
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── body-parser@1.5.2
remote:        ├── composable-middleware@0.3.0
remote:        ├── compression@1.0.11
remote:        ├── connect-mongo@0.4.2
remote:        ├── cookie-parser@1.0.1
remote:        ├── ejs@0.8.8
remote:        ├── errorhandler@1.0.2
remote:        ├── express@4.0.0
remote:        ├── express-session@1.0.4
remote:        ├── lodash@2.4.2
remote:        ├── method-override@1.0.2
remote:        ├── morgan@1.0.1
remote:        └── serve-favicon@2.0.1
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 21.9MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v15
remote:        https://swipt-frontend-staging.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To git@heroku.com:swipt-frontend-staging.git
 69ee061..374dfe6  master -> master

Done, without errors.
```

but I still have an application error like this

[image: heroku application error]

And here is the log

```
2015-11-11T13:41:04.533234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-11T13:41:07.021176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server/app.js`
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638326+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:892
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638337+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638346+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:31:13)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638336+00:00 app[web.1]:   return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638343+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638345+00:00 app[web.1]:     at favicon (/app/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:47:15)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638341+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638343+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/favicon.ico'
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638346+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:15:28)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638349+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638348+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638344+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:892:18)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
2015-11-11T13:41:08.638349+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
2015-11-11T13:41:09.275550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-11T13:41:09.286787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can't figure out where is the error.